# Assign user survey created by webform

Tags: users, nodes, webforms, quiz

I've created a survey using the webform module. I now want to assign a set of users to take the survey. Does anyone have any recommendation on how I should go about doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Role and assign set of users to that Role. Now go to your Webform configuration settings (Form Settings) >> Submission Access and assign newly created role to it.

For example in the following example I've created a 'moderator' rule and assigned users (those I want to assign users to take survey).

[image]

That's it. Now users under "Moderator" role only can access the form.